# How to run C# source generator in visual studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Recently I am updating my self to learn this new technology, however I cannot get the source generator running even I followed step-by-step to tutorial.

What I have done:

1. Create a solusion with a console application, then add a class library project. Both projects are .NET 5.
2. Install NuGet package `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces` for both projects.
3. In the class library project, write following code:

   ```
   using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
   using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;
   using System.Text;

   namespace ClassLibrary {
       [Generator]
       public class MySourceGenerator : ISourceGenerator {
           public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context) {
               context.AddSource("myGeneratedFile.cs", SourceText.From(@"
   namespace GeneratedNamespace
   {
       public class GeneratedClass
       {
           public static void GeneratedMethod()
           {
               // generated code
           }
       }
   }", Encoding.UTF8));
           }

           public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context) {
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. In the Main method of console application, write following code:

   ```
               GeneratedNamespace.GeneratedClass.GeneratedMethod();
   ```
5. In the .csproj of the console application, add following code:

   ```
     <ItemGroup>
       <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary_ExperimentalSourceGenerator\ClassLibrary_ExperimentalSourceGenerator.csproj"
                         OutputItemType="Analyzer"
                         ReferenceOutputAssembly="false" />
     </ItemGroup>
   ```
6. Build solution.
7. Recieve following error:

   > CS0103
   > The name 'GeneratedNamespace' does not exist in the current context
   > ConsoleApp1 D:\OneDrive\VS Solutions\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs

   And following warning:

   > CS8032
   > An instance of analyzer ClassLibrary.MySourceGenerator cannot be created from D:\OneDrive\VS Solutions\ClassLibrary_ExperimentalSourceGenerator\bin\Debug\net5.0\ClassLibrary_ExperimentalSourceGenerator.dll: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. System cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that your source generator assembly targets .NET 5.

Source generators must target `netstandard2.0` in order to work correctly within Visual Studio. This is because VS runs `net48` internally, so it cannot load code targeting newer frameworks.

The hint here is the error message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0...'